# Disparités dans l'emploi de l'article : « avoir peur » / « avoir du souci »

Tags: grammaire, verbes, articles

Je me demande pourquoi on utilise le partitif dans *avoir du souci* mais on n'utilise pas avec *avoir peur*. Si on ne peut pas compter la peur. Ou dans quelque phrase comme *avoir froid*, etc...

Comment: *se faire du souci* ou *avoir du souci* ? Cette deuxième expression ne m'est pas familière...

Comment: Avoir du souci à se faire?

Comment: Ça c'est un exemple pour *se faire du souci* comme *avoir des pâtes à manger*.

Comment: Oh d'accord. J'ai pensé que l'expression était "avoir du souci", mais bon, l'expression "se faire du souci " utilise le partitif encore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La peur est une émotion, par nature insécable, même si elle a plusieurs causes, elle s'emploie seule au singulier ; parfois elle est plurielle si l'on fait référence à une succession de peurs étalées dans le temps.

On peut en revanche avoir un ou plusieurs soucis simultanément ; ils sont dénombrables. Le partitif y trouve sa place naturellement.

Comment: Je ne comprend pas. On dit "J'ai de la chance" et on ne peut pas avoir un ou plusieurs chanceux. Donc, on utilise le partitif par des mots non comptables aussi?

Comment: @NicholasJ.  "On a une chance sur deux, ou sur `x` millions" ; la chance n'est pas une émotion mais la valorisation (avec la possibilité de décompte) d'un ou plusieurs événements.

Comment: Des émotions n'ont besoin pas de partitif, mais les mots abstraits comme "la chance" et "le souci" qui peuvent être comptés l'utilisent. C'est ça?

Comment: @NicholasJ. Je dirais plutôt : tout ce qui touche à la conscience par la sensibilité (ou les émotions) n'a pas besoin de partitif, alors que tout ce qui est évalué, valorisé par le mental en a besoin

Comment: de l'amour, de la haine, de la pitié, ... ?

Comment: @GAMPUB Ces sentiments ne touchent pas la conscience par la sensibilité, mais sont des projections mentales, des pulsions, voire des illusions. Quand on a de l'amour  (ou de la haine) pour quelqu'un, on n'est pas amoureux de l'univers tout entier, mais d'une partie seulement que l'on a sélectionné, et donc le mental est intervenu. Quand la (vraie) peur vous prend, elle vous prend tout entier, elle annihile votre mental (et votre ego), vous n'êtes plus le même, c'est une expérience entière. Si vous avez 'le coup de foudre' vous *êtes* amour[eux], totalement absorbé, plus rien n'est à vous.

Comment: @cl-r Est-ce que c'est la raison par laquelle on dit "j'ai du froid dans ma gorge"? Ou on dit "j'ai froid dans ma gorge"?

Comment: @NicholasJ. "J'ai froid dans *la* gorge", on peut dire aussi "dans *ma* gorge", mais c'est redondant : comme c'est moi qui parle, je ne peux pas avoir froid dans *ta* gorge.

Comment: @NicholasJ. Je dirais plutot "j'ai froid **à** la gorge". Utiliser "dans" n'est pas naturel pour moi...

Comment: @cl-r Merci. Je suis désolé j'ai demandé beaucoup de choses mais je voudrais savoir s'il y a un contexte où, par exemple, on dit "avoir de la faim". C'est à dire, où "la faim" soit valorisé par le mental. Peut être quand on parle d'un pays pauvre? Ou est-ce que "la faim n' aura besoin de partitif jamais?

Comment: @NicholasJ. *Faim* est du même domaine que *peur*, c'est quelque chose que le mental ne contrôle pas mais que le corps ressent. "J'ai faim, j'ai un peu faim, j'ai une faim de loup..." - P.S. L'expression utilisée par Random "J'ai froid **à** la gorge" est plus usuelle, plus naturelle que la mienne ; avec *dans*, on insiste vraiment pour situer et localiser l'endroit où le mal de gorge est ressenti, c'est dans la gorge et pas ailleurs.

Comment: @cl-r d'accord. Mille mercis.

Comment: C'est vraiment n'importe quoi ces explications. *J'ai espoir*, *j'ai emprise*, etc. De plus le partitif est contrairement à ce que tu dis utilisé pour des indénombrables. Il se trouve que les exemples dont tu parles sont à la fois dénombrables et indénombrables, ce qui ne fait qu'ajouter à la confusion.

Comment: *j'ai espoir* ne semble pas très courant : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=j%27ai+espoir%2Cj%27ai+l%27espoir&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cj%27ai%20l%27%20espoir%3B%2Cc0 ; mais espoir joue sur les deux tableaux que j'évoque : *Le fait d'espérer, d'attendre quelque chose avec confiance * (on a un/l'espoir), et par extension, *l'objet d'un espoir chose*, et aussi, la personne sur qui on fonde des espoirs : *L'espoir du tennis français* ; espoir est indénombrable ET dénombrable. L'utilisation du partitif indique une réification....

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez  ....donc la face dénombrable, donc quelque chose que le mental peut saisir, sinon l'utilisation du sens indénombrable ramène à la sensibilité, à la conscience.

Comment: *J'ai connaissance*, *j'ai conscience*… *J'ai le sentiment*, *j'ai le vertige*…

Comment: Ceux qui sont doubles : *J'ai les connaissances suffisantes pour... J'ai la conscience politique suffisamment* ... ; *sentiment* est plus complexe : c'est en effet une manifestation de la conscience, mais une manifestation partielle, le sentiment est multiforme, dénombrable, on peut avoir un ou plusieurs sentiments sur des sujets différents ; *vertige* est une impression, une distorsion des perceptions qui font croire que le monde alentour tourne, comme c'est une forme de croyance, c'est le mental qui a peur, on peut ré-éduquer le vertige en apprivoisant cette peur.